# After insert at the database knex do not send the data to database but returning the data

Tags: typescript, sqlite, express, knex.js

i have one problem with my sqlite3, knex, typescript and express routing.

After send the request to the database, my function returns my data but not show at my database.sqlite.

Function to create the data:

```
     async create(req: Request, res: Response) {

        const {
            name,
            email,
            whatsapp,
            latitude,
            longitude,
            city,
            uf,
            items
        } = req.body;

        const trx = await knex.transaction();

        const point = {
            name,
            email,
            whatsapp,
            latitude,
            longitude,
            city,
            uf,
            image: 'test'
        }



        const points = await trx('points').insert(point);
        const point_id = points[0];
        const receivedPointItems = items.map((item_id: number) => {
            return {
                item_id,
                point_id
            }
        })
        await trx('point_items').insert(receivedPointItems);

        return res.send({receivedPointItems, point});
    }
```

Connection.ts

```
const connection = knex({
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'database.sqlite'),
    }, 
    useNullAsDefault: true,
});
```

migration Point

```
export async function up(knex: Knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('points', (point) => {
        point.increments('id').primary();
        point.string('name').notNullable();
        point.string('image').notNullable();
        point.string('email').notNullable();
        point.string('city').notNullable();
        point.string('whatsapp').notNullable();
        point.string('uf', 2).notNullable();
        point.decimal('longitude').notNullable();
        point.decimal('latitude').notNullable()
    })
}

export async function down(knex: Knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('points');
}
```

items migration:

```
export async function up(knex: Knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('items', (point) => {
     point.increments('id').primary();
     point.string('title').notNullable();
     point.string('image').notNullable();
  })
}

export async function down(knex: Knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('items');
}
```

point_items migration:

```
export async function up(knex: Knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('point_items', (point) => {
        point.increments('id').primary();
        point.string('point_id').notNullable().references('id').inTable('points');
        point.string('item_id').notNullable().references('id').inTable('items');
    })
}

export async function down(knex: Knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('point_items');
}
```

After run my code to migrate and create all the tables of database, and create my file "database.sqlite", and run the knex seed to insert in the table items all pre-registered items, my database is: [image: database after migration]

And after send the req to the server return the object created but not insert at the database as you see in the image:[image: database after send req]

Answer (score 0):

Only use at finish the transaction

```
await trx.commit()
```